# PYTHON: How do I create a list of every possible letter mapping using a dictionary that stores every possible letter mapping combination?

Tags: python, dictionary, cryptography, mapping, one-to-one

I am working on a program that breaks one-to-one mapping ciphers where the current state is stored in a dictionary that contains the possible mappings for each letter. Each letter key contains a list of the letters that it could possibly be mapped to. In the end, there should only be one letter in each letter's list. For this problem, the dictionary would look like this with the respective (key : value) pairs:

```
'A' : ['A']
'B' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z']
'C' : ['C']
'D' : ['D']
'E' : ['E']
'F' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z']
'G' : ['G', 'W']
'H' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z']
'I' : ['I']
'J' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z']
'K' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z']
'L' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z']
'M' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z']
'N' : ['N']
'O' : ['O']
'P' : ['P']
'Q' : ['Q']
'R' : ['R']
'S' : ['S']
'T' : ['T']
'U' : ['U']
'V' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z']
'W' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z']
'X' : ['X']
'Y' : ['Y']
'Z' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z']
```

How would I create a list that contains every possible mapping situation as an element? Such a list would contain each possible dictionary where every letter key has exactly one letter value in its list. This would serve to find all possible mappings with this current state. An example element would be the dictionary:

```
'A' : ['A']
'B' : ['B']
'C' : ['C']
'D' : ['D']
'E' : ['E']
'F' : ['F']
'G' : ['G']
'H' : ['H']
'I' : ['I']
'J' : ['J']
'K' : ['K']
'L' : ['L']
'M' : ['M']
'N' : ['N']
'O' : ['O']
'P' : ['P']
'Q' : ['Q']
'R' : ['R']
'S' : ['S']
'T' : ['T']
'U' : ['U']
'V' : ['V']
'W' : ['W']
'X' : ['X']
'Y' : ['Y']
'Z' : ['Z']
```

Comment: I edited the first paragraph. I hope that helped to elaborate it more.

Comment: There are 51,874,849,202 single-letter mappings that can be generated by drawing from the dictionary you defined. Even if each mapping were stored in 26*2 chars, this would take 2.7 terabytes to store.

Comment: I may be doing the math wrong, but considering there are only 11 letters that are in question, and each letter can only map to one unique letter, there should only be 11! = 39,916,800 mapping situations. Is that not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I agree with MRule. There would be 51,874,849,202 single-letter mappings in total. Consider the following approach (in python 2.7):

```
import itertools
from collections import OrderedDict
import string
seed = {
'A' : ['A'],
'B' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z'],
'C' : ['C'],
'D' : ['D'],
'E' : ['E'],
'F' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z'],
'G' : ['G', 'W'],
'H' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z'],
'I' : ['I'],
'J' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z'],
'K' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z'],
'L' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z'],
'M' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z'],
'N' : ['N'],
'O' : ['O'],
'P' : ['P'],
'Q' : ['Q'],
'R' : ['R'],
'S' : ['S'],
'T' : ['T'],
'U' : ['U'],
'V' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z'],
'W' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z'],
'X' : ['X'],
'Y' : ['Y'],
'Z' : ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z'] 
}
d = OrderedDict(sorted(seed.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
listOfList = d.values()
for i in itertools.product(* listOfList):
    # print the possible dict
    print dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase, i))
```

**UPDATE:** `To only calculate the possible dictionaries where every mapped letter is unique`, you could do:

```
import itertools
import string
others = ['B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'V', 'W', 'Z']
# this dict is fixed
dict1 = {k : [k] for k in string.uppercase if k not in others}
# iterate all possibles in others, then merge two dicts into one
for i in itertools.permutations(others):
    dict2 = dict(zip(others, i))
    print dict(dict1.items() + dict2.items())
```

Comment: This is somewhat helpful. However, since no letter can be mapped to more than once, is there a way to only calculate the possible dictionaries where every mapped letter is unique? This would greatly reduce the number of possibilities.

Comment: Yep, that's great! Thanks!